# User error: "funding_source" is an invalid render array key

Tags: commerce

This seems to be related to Commerce orders and the Symfony Mailer module. I intermittently see this error when a user attempts to complete the checkout process using Commerce PayPal:

> Blockquote
> User error: "funding_source" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 98 of /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php)
> #0 /var/www/site/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(347): _drupal_error_handler_real()
> #1 [internal function]: _drupal_error_handler()
> #2 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php(98): trigger_error()
> #3 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(404): Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children()
> #4 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender()
> #5 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(479): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render()
> #6 /var/www/site/web/sites/default/files/php/twig/6529302194f2f_commerce-order.html.twig_2p-K4ggEbyH1Y08LLASzZvkUF/lEl50_59oVkz1bTgwQDbm4t-UDXyh-LQi70GrCZvt-Y.php(44): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter()
> #7 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_a737a4a270bc020c6c35483b73b12bb8->doDisplay()
> #8 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
> #9 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display()
> #10 /var/www/site/web/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(55): Twig\Template->render()
> #11 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template()
> #12 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(433): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render()
> #13 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender()
> #14 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(479): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render()
> #15 /var/www/site/web/sites/default/files/php/twig/6529302194f2f___string_template__c0e1ea_CN1J_WKEj7CUghI835RNG-N3T/QGF5E63NnWsxeN7rwaH9gK3ZBMZdwdU_71Pac_bLOP8.php(52): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter()
> #16 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_4798832cb62276a94273997f6ae59d7e->doDisplay()
> #17 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
> #18 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display()
> #19 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(45): Twig\Template->render()
> #20 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigEnvironment.php(234): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render()
> #21 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/symfony_mailer/src/Plugin/EmailAdjuster/BodyEmailAdjuster.php(75): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment->renderInline()
> #22 [internal function]: Drupal\symfony_mailer\Plugin\EmailAdjuster\BodyEmailAdjuster->preRenderVariables()
> #23 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Security/DoTrustedCallbackTrait.php(101): call_user_func_array()
> #24 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(788): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback()
> #25 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(374): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback()
> #26 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender()
> #27 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(479): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render()
> #28 /var/www/site/web/sites/default/files/php/twig/6529302194f2f_email.html.twig_Be65fSN2NURPnSHvFrCJkJ-VJ/J8ORnB2UzlbntcueOpSzbuv92fcZzaqOq2p2BZO7rJo.php(42): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter()
> #29 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_25218f115be83ddbfa265487c92c8563->doDisplay()
> #30 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
> #31 /var/www/site/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display()
> #32 /var/www/site/web/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(55): Twig\Template->render()
> #33 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template()
> #34 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(433): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render()
> #35 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(204): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender()
> #36 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(160): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render()
> #37 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(580): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render{closure}()
> #38 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(161): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
> #39 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/symfony_mailer/src/Email.php(538): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderPlain()
> #40 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/symfony_mailer/src/Mailer.php(233): Drupal\symfony_mailer\Email->render()
> #41 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/symfony_mailer/src/Mailer.php(149): Drupal\symfony_mailer\Mailer->doSend()
> #42 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(580): Drupal\symfony_mailer\Mailer->Drupal\symfony_mailer{closure}()
> #43 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/symfony_mailer/src/Mailer.php(158): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
> #44 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/symfony_mailer/src/Email.php(292): Drupal\symfony_mailer\Mailer->send()
> #45 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/symfony_mailer/src/MailManagerReplacement.php(92): Drupal\symfony_mailer\Email->send()
> #46 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/src/MailHandler.php(105): Drupal\symfony_mailer\MailManagerReplacement->mail()
> #47 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/src/Mail/OrderReceiptMail.php(76): Drupal\commerce\MailHandler->sendMail()
> #48 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/src/EventSubscriber/OrderReceiptSubscriber.php(63): Drupal\commerce_order\Mail\OrderReceiptMail->send()
> #49 [internal function]: Drupal\commerce_order\EventSubscriber\OrderReceiptSubscriber->sendOrderReceipt()
> #50 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(142): call_user_func()
> #51 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/state_machine/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/StateItem.php(422): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch()
> #52 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/state_machine/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/StateItem.php(389): Drupal\state_machine\Plugin\Field\FieldType\StateItem->dispatchTransitionEvent()
> #53 [internal function]: Drupal\state_machine\Plugin\Field\FieldType\StateItem->postSave()
> #54 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldItemList.php(233): call_user_func_array()
> #55 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldItemList.php(198): Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList->delegateMethod()
> #56 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList->postSave()
> #57 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(938): call_user_func_array()
> #58 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(970): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeFieldMethod()
> #59 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(896): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeFieldPostSave()
> #60 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/src/CommerceContentEntityStorage.php(56): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeHook()
> #61 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/src/OrderStorage.php(81): Drupal\commerce\CommerceContentEntityStorage->invokeHook()
> #62 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(598): Drupal\commerce_order\OrderStorage->invokeHook()
> #63 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(781): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPostSave()
> #64 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(523): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPostSave()
> #65 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php(804): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save()
> #66 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/src/OrderStorage.php(159): Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save()
> #67 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityBase.php(339): Drupal\commerce_order\OrderStorage->save()
> #68 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/checkout/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutFlow/CheckoutFlowBase.php(220): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->save()
> #69 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/payment/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutPane/PaymentProcess.php(180): Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowBase->redirectToStep()
> #70 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/checkout/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutFlow/CheckoutFlowWithPanesBase.php(546): Drupal\commerce_payment\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\PaymentProcess->buildPaneForm()
> #71 [internal function]: Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowWithPanesBase->buildForm()
> #72 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(536): call_user_func_array()
> #73 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(283): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm()
> #74 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(224): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm()
> #75 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/checkout/src/Controller/CheckoutController.php(143): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
> #76 [internal function]: Drupal\commerce_checkout\Controller\CheckoutController->formPage()
> #77 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array()
> #78 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(580): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> #79 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
> #80 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext()
> #81 /var/www/site/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(169): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> #82 /var/www/site/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(81): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
> #83 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle()
> #84 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle()
> #85 /var/www/site/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle()
> #86 /var/www/site/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass()
> #87 /var/www/site/web/modules/contrib/cleantalk/src/EventSubscriber/BootSubscriber.php(193): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle()
> #88 /var/www/site/web/core/modules/ban/src/BanMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\cleantalk\EventSubscriber\BootSubscriber->handle()
> #89 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle()
> #90 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle()
> #91 /var/www/site/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle()
> #92 /var/www/site/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(718): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle()
> #93 /var/www/site/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle()
> #94 {main}

Is this an order email twig template issue, or something else?

Comment: This is an array key with no render child. It can be anywhere, in templates but also in variables the templates render. I would set a breakpoint in a debugger, or you could try a full-text search for the invalid key, this doesn't look like it will get you too many search hits.

Comment: There are only a few places in the code where I can find 'funding_source' used as an array index:


modules/contrib/commerce_paypal/commerce_paypal.module:  return $funding_sources[$funding_source] ?? '';
modules/contrib/commerce_paypal/commerce_paypal.module:    if (!empty($data['funding_source'])) {
modules/contrib/commerce_paypal/commerce_paypal.module:      $variables['order']['funding_source'] = commerce_paypal_funding_source_label($data['funding_source']);

Answer (score 0):

To create a valid render array, put the string the function returns in a markup render element:

```
$variables['order']['funding_source'] = ['#markup' => commerce_paypal_funding_source_label($data['funding_source'])];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.